# Validate to ensure no duplicates in Google Forms column

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am looking to create a Google Form for PIN codes. I would like the users to be able to select their own 4-digit PIN code, but I can't have any duplicate PINs.

I can't figure out how to setup Google Forms to reference a column in a spreadsheet for duplicates before allowing the user to submit the form. This would be similar to the "Username is already taken" in PHP forms. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are disallowing duplicate PINs? For security reasons, it is always better to *allow* them if at all possible, assuming they're being used like passwords, since otherwise an attacker can determine that a given PIN is in use easily by attempting to set it, and then narrow down which user has it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with Google Forms.  You'll need to use something else.  You'll need to design an HTML form, and put it into Google Sites, or a Stand Alone Web App using Apps Script.  You could have code check for duplicates AFTER the Google Form is submitted, delete the response, then send an email to the user to that their PIN is invalid, and to choose another one.